# How to create a custom Grails query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to Grails and I've some troubles with queries. I got two domain classes like this:

```
class Cliente {

    String nombre
    String cuit
    String localidad
    String establecimiento

    static hasMany = [facturas: Factura]
}

class Factura {

    String Proveedor
    int sucursal
    String numero
    String letraFactura
    Cliente cliente
    Date fecha
    String tipo
}
```

I want to list all elements in `facturas` with client name:

Result expected:

```
Proveedor|sucursal|numero|cliente_nombre|fecha
```

I've tried some different ways but always get the `cliente_id` not `cliente_nombre`.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what your goal is; do you want a map with the given fields returned from a query?  Why does the list of facturas need the client name when that is what you are search on?

Comment: @tylerwal I want to select all the items in the Factura table but replacing the cliente_id by cliente_name. In mysql I'd do a join between Factura and Cliente.I hope I have been a little more clear.

Comment: @ConejoNegro Put your clarification in your question, i.e. edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I know what you are asking: given a client name, return a list of `factura`'s, with the stipulation that the list of fields should contain the client name rather than the client id.

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

// given a client name
def clientNameToSearch = 'some name'

def crit = Factura.createCriteria()

def results = crit.list() {
    createAlias('cliente', 'cli')
    eq('cli.nombre', clientNameToSearch)

    // optional transformer to output a map rather than a list
    resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)

    projections {
        property('Proveedor', 'Proveedor')
        property('sucursal', 'sucursal')
        property('numero', 'numero')
        property('cli.nombre', 'clienteNombre')
        property('fecha', 'fecha')
    }
}
```

`results` would then contain a list of maps, with each map having this structure:

```
[
    Proveedor: ...,
    sucursal: ...,
    numero: ...,
    clienteNombre: ...,
    fecha: ...
]
```

Comment: why do you use a createAlias ? I does not have sense for me. If you want to filter for something, just create the conditions in blocks. It is much easier: cliente{ eq('nombre', clientNameToSearch) }

Comment: It's essentially doing the same thing as far as I'm aware (inner join on the `cliente` table), so functionality is the same.  And I'm using the alias within the projections below, does the nested closure syntax support the same functionality?

Comment: Not always, but in this case It is. Of course the result will the same, but if there is a cleaner way to doing things, why dont use it? I prefer a cleaner code, when it is possible. For me createAlias is useful but in certain situations, when blocks dont work, as n to m relations, for example

Comment: There is a spanish expression that says: "killing flies with cannons" hehehe ;)

Comment: I don't believe you answered my question: I'm using the alias within the projections below, does the nested closure syntax support the same functionality?

Comment: Yes, you can use blocks inside projections.

Comment: Operator.withCriteria {
    creatorUser{
        eq("username", "manuel")
    }
    projections{
        creatorUser{
            property("username")
        }
    }
}

Comment: I was actually referring to using the original `createUser` defined within criteria portion in the `projections` block rather than redoing the nested structure.  It's obviously personal opinion because I think the `createAlias` syntax is cleaner than repeated nested closures.

Comment: For me, it is in more java style, but both points of views are correct :)